# What's wrong in this URL-Request that not give proper output in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

In this below example the code given unsuccessful output. The first is GET request and and take cookies and after send post request and set cookie with many headers and parameters like below. So, please help me for the successful response from post request this request work in android but same not work in IOS(swift). Please give me any suggestion or example or solution for it OR please tell me is that proper way or not.

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102")
    var req = URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "GET"

    let datatask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) {(data, resp, err) in

        if data == nil
        {
            print("something wrong")
            return
        }

        let htttp = resp as! HTTPURLResponse?
        print(htttp!.statusCode)

        if err == nil && (htttp?.statusCode)! <= 500
        {
            self.cookie = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: (resp?.url!)!)

            do
            {
                let str = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))as String?

                self.swift = try SwiftSoup.parse(str!)
                var first = try self.swift.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "javax.faces.ViewState").first()

                if first == nil
                {
                    first = try self.swift.getElementById("j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0")
                }

                self.vhtype = (try first?.attr("value"))!

                let s = (Element.self, try SwiftSoup.parse(str!).body()?.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("id","form_rcdl:j_idt").select("button").get(0).attr("id"))//.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
                self.str2 = s.1!

            }
            catch
            {}


            let posturl = URL(string: "https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcDlHome.xhtml")
            var postreq = URLRequest(url: posturl!)
            postreq.httpMethod = "POST"
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(self.cookie, for: posturl!, mainDocumentURL: nil)

            postreq.setValue("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
            postreq.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            postreq.setValue("application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            postreq.setValue("parivahan.gov.in", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
            postreq.setValue("en-US,en;q=0.5", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
            postreq.setValue("gzip, deflate, br", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept-encoding")
            postreq.setValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
            postreq.setValue("partial/ajax", forHTTPHeaderField: "Faces-Request")
            postreq.setValue("https://parivahan.gov.in/", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
            let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) " + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140" + "Safari/537.36"
            postreq.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

            let postparam = ["javax.faces.partial.ajax" : "true" ,
                             "javax.faces.source" : self.str2,
                             "javax.faces.partial.execute" : "@all",
                             "javax.faces.partial.render" : "form_rcdl:pnl_show form_rcdl:pg_show  form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl" ,
                             self.str2 : self.str2 ,
                             "form_rcdl" : "form_rcdl" ,
                             "form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1" : self.regno1,
                             "form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2" : self.regno2,
                             "javax.faces.ViewState": self.vhtype]


            do
            {
                postreq.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postparam, options: [])
            } catch {
                print(error,"error in postreq body")
            }

            print(self.str2)
            print(self.regno1,"reg no1")
            print(self.regno2,"reg no2")


            let posttask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postreq, completionHandler: {(data, response, err) in

                if let http = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                {
                    print(http.statusCode)
                }
                if err == nil
                {
                    let con = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue))as String?
                    //                        let con = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print(con!,"post urlrequest content")
                }
            })

            posttask.resume()


        }
        else
        {
            print("status code > 500 bad response")

            if err != nil
            {
                print(err!)
            }
        }
    } // main datatask

    datatask.resume()
```

i used [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) Library for get HTML element in swift. That use in above GET-Request.

**The response of post-request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
   <changes>
      <eval><![CDATA[PrimeFaces.ajax.Utils.loadStylesheets(['/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/grid-css.css?ln=css','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/layout.css?ln=css','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/css/bootstrap.min.css?ln=bootstrap-3.3.7','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/components.css?ln=primefaces&v=6.0']);PrimeFaces.ajax.Utils.loadScripts(['/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.0','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.0','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/core.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.0','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/components.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.0','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/keyfilter/keyfilter.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.0','/rcdlstatus/vahan/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces']);]]></eval>
      <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[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]]></update>
   </changes>
</partial-response>
```

**Expexting Response is like:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl"><![CDATA[<div id="form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all datatable-panel" data-widget="widget_form_rcdl_rcdl_pnl"><div id="form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl_header" class="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-panel-title">Know your RC Status</span></div><div id="form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content"><div id="form_rcdl:j_idt14" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div><div id="form_rcdl:j_idt27" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget">
                            <div class="ui-grid-row bottom-space">
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-4 resp-blank-height"></div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
                                    <label class="field-label resp-label-section right-position "><label id="form_rcdl:j_idt29" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget top-space field-label-mandate" for="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1">Registration No.<span class="ui-outputlabel-rfi">*</span></label>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-col-3"><input id="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1" name="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1" type="text" value="gj05fl" autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" placeholder="DL10ABC" size="20" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,p:&quot;form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1&quot;,u:&quot;form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1&quot;});" disabled="disabled" style="width: 48% !important" aria-required="true" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled input top-space inline-section" /><script id="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("InputText","widget_form_rcdl_tf_reg_no1",{id:"form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1"});</script><input id="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2" name="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2" type="text" value="9124" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" placeholder="1234" size="15" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,p:&quot;form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2&quot;,u:&quot;form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2&quot;});" disabled="disabled" style="width: 42% !important" aria-required="true" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled input top-space inline-section" /><script id="form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("InputText","widget_form_rcdl_tf_reg_no2",{id:"form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2"});</script>
                                </div>
                            </div></div>

                        <div class="ui-grid-row bottom-space center-position">
                            <div class="ui-grid-col-12"><button id="form_rcdl:j_idt43" name="form_rcdl:j_idt43" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form_rcdl:j_idt43&quot;,u:&quot;form_rcdl:pnl_show form_rcdl:pg_show form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl&quot;,onst:function(cfg){PF('block_ui').show();;},onsu:function(data,status,xhr){PF('block_ui').hide();;}});return false;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Check Status</span></button><script id="form_rcdl:j_idt43_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_form_rcdl_j_idt43",{id:"form_rcdl:j_idt43"});</script><button id="form_rcdl:rest_bt" name="form_rcdl:rest_bt" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Reset</span></button><script id="form_rcdl:rest_bt_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_form_rcdl_rest_bt",{id:"form_rcdl:rest_bt"});</script>                    
                            </div>
                        </div></div></div><script id="form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("Panel","widget_form_rcdl_rcdl_pnl",{id:"form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl"});</script>]]></update><update id="form_rcdl:pnl_show"><![CDATA[<div id="form_rcdl:pnl_show" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget datatable-panel"><span id="form_rcdl:pg_show">


<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-12">

        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive"><div id="form_rcdl:rcPanel" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"><div id="form_rcdl:j_idt67" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget">
                    <div class="center-position bottom-space">
                        <span class="font-bold text-underline">Vehicle Details Showing in Registering Authority</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-bold top-space bottom-space text-capitalize">
                        Registering Authority:  SURAT, GUJARAT
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 15%"><span class="font-bold">Registration No:</span></td>
                            <td style="width: 45%"><span class="">GJ05FL9124</span></td>
                            <td style="width: 15%"><span class="font-bold">Registration Date:</span></td>
                            <td>06-Oct-2008</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Chassis No:</span></td>
                            <td>MBLHA10EL8GGXXXXX</td>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Engine No:</span></td>
                            <td>HA10EB8GGXXXXX</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Owner Name:</span> </td>
                            <td colspan="4">BHUPATBHAI</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Vehicle Class:</span> </td>
                            <td>M-CYCLE/SCOOTER (2)</td>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Fuel Type:</span></td>
                            <td>PETROL</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Maker / Model:</span></td>
                            <td colspan="3">HERO HONDA MOTORS  LTD / PASSION PLUS MAC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Fitness Upto:</span></td>
                            <td>05-Oct-2023</td>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Insurance Upto:</span></td>
                            <td>29-Oct-2017</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Fuel Norms:</span> </td>
                            <td>NOT AVAILABLE</td>
                            <td><span class="font-bold">Tax Paid Upto:</span></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div></span></div>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[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]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Comment: I also this type of error in partial-response but i can't get solution.

Comment: Could you tell what you are expecting in the response. It looks like response is getting, is that an error response? Also have you missed to add post urlrequest content
?

Comment: yes, In this expecting response the one table in table tag like above edited answer.

Comment: Very unclear question, is the response you get a normal (but unexpected) result or an error? What are you asking about, the swift code or the content of your post message?

Comment: The response of post request is as error or unexpected and the expected result is last in my answer.